# Difference in returning a function between using explicit and implicit returns

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a working javascript code snippet that works in a Node application. The db_location defined as database layer as below is used by a route.

```
const db_location = {
  getLocations:() =>
    fetch(`${p_conf.SERVER_URL}/parse` + '/classes/GCUR_LOCATION', { method: 'GET', headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'APPLICATION_ID',
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'restAPIKey'
    }}).then(res1 => res1.json())
};
module.exports = db_location
```

The db_location defined a getLocations function which uses an implicit return. However, if I converted it to traditional explicit return, it didn't work any more.

```
const db_location = {
  getLocations: function() {
    fetch(`${p_conf.SERVER_URL}/parse` + '/classes/GCUR_LOCATION', { method: 'GET', headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'APPLICATION_ID',
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'restAPIKey'
    }}).then(res1 => res1.json())
  }
};
module.exports = db_location
```

I am having difficulty understanding if is this convertable and how the explicit return differs from the implicit counterpart?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions - it's not an "implicit return", it's entirely different syntax for function definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have any explicit return in the bottom code; `getLocations` is currently returning `undefined`. Change to:

```
const db_location = {
  getLocations: function() {
    return fetch(`${p_conf.SERVER_URL}/parse` ...
```

so that the promise chain is returned.